# Access the map type fields of the static class, and use the keyset() method to obtain its key set, but it is always empty

Tags: java, multithreading, keyset

This is the class I defined, he has a static field PubMsgs.

```
class storage{
    private static Map<String, List<String>> subLists = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<String, List<Request>> pubMsgs = new HashMap<>();
    private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void printPubMsgs(){
        lock.lock();
        Set<String> keyss = subLists.keySet();
        System.out.println("keyss:" + keyss);
        Set<String> keys = pubMsgs.keySet();
        System.out.println("keys:" + keys);
        for (String key :
                keys) {
            List<Request> list = pubMsgs.get(key);
            System.out.println("list1:" + list.toString());
            Iterator<Request> iterator = list.listIterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator);
                System.out.println("here");
            }
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

}
```

I call its printPubMsgs method in other places, but he always returns empty, and I'm sure I have added elements before.

I tried to debug and found that the size of the map in the printPubMsgs function is 0.
[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVrZb.png)
I confirmed that he should not be 0, because another thread sends a request to storage, he still has a return.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXSyj.png)

---

Let me explain a little more clearly.
First, the publisher publishes some news. These messages are accepted by the instance of topic class, and the instance calls the method addMessage of the storage class to store these messages in the storage class.
[published](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMEYQ.png)
[accepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jnEV.png)

```
public static void addMessage(Request request) {
    lock.lock();
    if (pubMsgs.containsKey(request.getSource())) {
        pubMsgs.get(request.getSource()).add(request);
    } else {
        List<Request> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(request);
        pubMsgs.put(request.getSource(), list);
    }
    lock.unlock();
}
```

---

This project is to simulate a message queue, I use multithreading to simulate the concurrency scenario of multiple subscribers and publishers.

---

I post the key code of my project below.
Publisher.java

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());) {

        oos.writeObject(new Request(pubHead, msg, id));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Subscriber.java

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try (Socket s = new Socket(address, port);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());) {
            oos.writeObject(new Request(subHead, sub_id, id));
            oos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
            ObjectOutputStream oos1 = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());) {
            oos1.writeObject(new Request(getHead, "", id));
//            sleep(1000);
            while (true) {
                ObjectInputStream ooi = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Request req = (Request) ooi.readObject();
                if (Objects.equals(req.getHead(), wrongHead)) {
                    System.out.println(req.getBody());
                    break;
                } else if (Objects.equals(req.getHead(), completeHead)) {
                    System.out.println(req.getBody());
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(req.getBody());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Topic.java

```
@Override
public void run() {
    storage.update();
    try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());){
        Request req = (Request) ois.readObject();
        if (req.getHead().equals(pubHead)) {
            System.out.println(">>> Successfully receive publish request");
            storage.addMessage(req);
        } else if (req.getHead().equals(getHead)) {
            System.out.println(">>> Successfully receive get request");
            List<Request> res = storage.getMessage(req.getSource());
            if (res == null) {
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(new Request(wrongHead, "you should subscribe first", "topic"));
            } else if (res.isEmpty()) {
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(new Request(wrongHead, "there are no messages from whom you subscribe", "topic"));
            } else {
                for (Request re : res) {
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(re);
                }
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(new Request(completeHead, ">>> all messages have been gotten", "topic"));
            }
        } else if (req.getHead().equals(subHead)) {
            storage.accessSub(req.getSource(), req.getBody());
            System.out.println(">>> Successfully receive subscribe request");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Storage.java

```
class storage{
    private static Map<String, List<String>> subLists = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<String, List<Request>> pubMsgs = new HashMap<>();
    private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void printPubMsgs(){
        lock.lock();
        Set<String> keyss = subLists.keySet();
        System.out.println("keyss:" + keyss);
        Set<String> keys = pubMsgs.keySet();
        System.out.println("keys:" + keys);
        for (String key :
                keys) {
            List<Request> list = pubMsgs.get(key);
            System.out.println("list1:" + list.toString());
            Iterator<Request> iterator = list.listIterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator);
                System.out.println("here");
            }
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public static void addMessage(Request request) {
        lock.lock();
        if (pubMsgs.containsKey(request.getSource())) {
            pubMsgs.get(request.getSource()).add(request);
        } else {
            List<Request> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(request);
            pubMsgs.put(request.getSource(), list);
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public static List<Request> getMessage(String source) {
        lock.lock();
        List<Request> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (subLists.containsKey(source)) {
            List<String> list = subLists.get(source);
            for (String s : list) {
                if (!pubMsgs.containsKey(s)) continue;
                for (Request req : pubMsgs.get(s)) {
                    result.add(new Request(req.getHead(), req.getBody(), req.getSource()));
                }
            }
        } else {
            lock.unlock();
            return null; // wrong request
        }
        lock.unlock();
        return result; // if empty --> wrong request
    }

    public static void accessSub(String source, String destination) {
        lock.lock();
        if (subLists.containsKey(source)) {
            subLists.get(source).add(destination);
        } else {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(destination);
            subLists.put(source, list);
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    /**
     * if the existence exceed 1000s, then remove
     */
    public static void update() {
        lock.lock();
        Set<String> keys = pubMsgs.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            List<Request> list = pubMsgs.get(key);
            Iterator<Request> iterator = list.listIterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Date now = new Date();
                Date date = iterator.next().getDate();
                if ((now.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000 > 1000) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    System.out.println("test");
                }
            }
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: you don't put any data in them, and you don't understand why they are empty?

Comment: I really don't know what you expect us to tell you. You already debugged your code far enugh that you know the problem: Your map that you try to print has size 0 and therefor you never added any elements to it. This is your problem and what you need to fix. Since you didn't include any complete example that shows how you fill your map and it's lists we can't tell you any details of what you did wrong, but you certainly did not add any elements to the map/list you try to print. Simply saying "should not be 0" doesn't help or solve anything. The size is 0 and that wasn't done by evil magic.

Comment: On a different note, why are you declaring your maps static?  Every instance of storage class will share those exact same maps.  Is that what you want?   If so, you should probably declare the default constructor as private.  And class names, by convention, start with uppercase.

Comment: @ON GOD SPIDERS I have updated my description. I appreciate your time.

Comment: I think that because Subscriber can receive messages, the map in storage should not be empty

Comment: How should I fix this problem?

Comment: It feels like publishers can send messages properly, subscriber can receive messages properly, but when I try to print those messages, they have been gone.